# How to refer to seekbars which are inside a for loop and set their progress with onclick method?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclick

My for loop looks like this:

```
for (short i = 0; i < bands; i++) {
            final short band = i;

            // Setup textview to label the frequency band (with center frequency)
            TextView freqTextView = new TextView(this);

            freqTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            freqTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            freqTextView.setText((mService.getCenterFreq((int)band) / 1000) + " Hz");
            mLinearLayout.addView(freqTextView);

            // now we have a 3-part linearlayout, consisting of lower dB limit label,
            // then the slider bar (SeekBar), then the higher dB limit text label
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // Set up lower dB limit text label
            TextView minDbTextView = new TextView(this);
            minDbTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            minDbTextView.setText((mService.getBandLevelLow() / 100) + " dB");

            // Set up higher dB limit text label
            TextView maxDbTextView = new TextView(this);
            maxDbTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            maxDbTextView.setText((mService.getBandLevelHigh() / 100) + " dB");

            // Set up SeekBar for this band
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.weight = 1;
            final SeekBar bar =new SeekBar(this);
             bar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            // Assign the seekbar the appropriate max value
            bar.setMax(mService.getBandLevelHigh() - mService.getBandLevelLow());
            // Apply the current value to the seekbar
            bar.setProgress(mService.getBandLevel((int)band)-mService.getBandLevelLow());

            // Set up so that when seekbar changes for a certain band, we update the
            // actual value of the band in our Equalizer object in the EqService class
            bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


                public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {



                    try {
                        mService.setBandLevel((int)band, (int) (progress + mService.getBandLevelLow()));


                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                }
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
            });


            row.addView(minDbTextView);
            row.addView(bar);
            row.addView(maxDbTextView);

            // Add the total band into the main linearlayout


            mLinearLayout.addView(row);



        }
```

And this is my button

```
Button jazz = new Button(this);
        jazz.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        jazz.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        jazz.setText("jazz");
        mLinearLayout.addView(jazz);
        jazz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "jezz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
```

In public void onClick i want to setprogress values in each seekbar item. For Example when i click button jazz i set progress 1seekbar to 100 2nd to 500 3rd 40 4th 1 5th 5000

so my activty with seekbars is like:

[image]

i clicked button pop an set different values to all seekbars.
[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be clear, could you elaborate in better words?

Comment: my loop for throws me 5 seekbars. How refer to them ? i want on click event. when i click button-> set five progresses with defualt values in 5 seekbars.

Comment: Um, an array would work.

Comment: How this array should looks like ? I am not familiar with java sorry.